# Hyper-V disconnects enhanced session after sleep

Tags: hyper-v

I am using Hyper-V on laptop with Windows 10 Pro to connect to an Ubuntu 18.04 VM using the enhanced session mode.

Things generally work well except that sometimes when the laptop sleeps and then wakes up, I get a message that I have been disconnected from the VM. The VM is still running and any background processes I had running are still alive. (I verify this by using `screen` to start a shell session and confirm that it is still alive).

The problem is that all the stuff on my desktop like my browser, emacs window, etc. all get killed and it looks like I login to a fresh desktop session.

Any suggestions on the following would be welcome:

1. How can I get Hyper-V to not disconnect me after sleep?
2. Failing that, is there a better way to login with an enhanced session? Hyper-V shows lots of options in addition to `Xorg` (which is the one I use since none of the others seem to work by default); is there an easy way to make some of the other modes work?
3. I am tempted to try the instructions in (https://www.tenforums.com/virtualization/107147-guide-how-run-ubuntu-18-04-enhanced-mode-hyper-v.html) but that thread says that guide is superseded by the new Hyper-V quick create.

Thanks.